# File.Create fails on iPhone 5S

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity game that saves/loads data. I am in the testing phase for this project, and ran into an unusual circumstance in which the game refuses to save in iOS. It works just fine when run on Android, Windows, and OS X. Here is my applicable code:

```
FileStream file = File.Create(GetSavePath());
bf.Serialize(file, saveFile);
file.Close();
```

I define `GetSavePath()` as follows:

```
private string GetSavePath()
{
    return Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, SAVEPATH);
}
```

I define `SAVEPATH` as `SaveFile.bin`. Please note that the issue is explicitly with `File.Create()`, as seen in the trace below:

```
IOException: Sharing violation on path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4AE45A80-AC36-4A96-9C69-BE01CB753896/Documents/SaveFile.bin
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.File.Create (System.String path, Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.File.Create (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SaveManager.Save () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SaveManager.NewSave () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GameManager.NewSave () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at TitleManager.NewGame () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

From the above, it should be noted that `Invoke` is called since the user must click a button to create a new game. The issue with `System.IO.File.Create` in the trace corresponds to the `FileStream file = File.Create(GetSavePath());` above.

Device information:

- iPhone 5S
- iOS 10.1

Unity version: 5.4.1f1

I have yet to test on other iOS devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `File.Open()` with the mode `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` instead of `File.Create()`. Current speculation is that `File.Create()` fails to immediately release a lock on the file preventing the returned filestream from accessing the file.

Comment: Just discovered this, and it is indeed the solution! Weird... Still works on all other platforms, at least!