# Unity - IOS persistentDataPath access denied // Could not open database

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I am trying to recover a file from my streamingAssets and make a copy of it in the persistentDataPath.

The problem is that access to persistentDataPath is denied by iOS, so I cannot write the file, can someone tell me why?

Code:

```
#elif UNITY_IOS
if (File.Exists(Application.dataPath + "/Raw/" + StaticDatas.databaseName))
{
    byte[] bytes = null;
       if (File.Exists(Application.dataPath + "/Raw/" + StaticDatas.databaseName))
       {
        Debug.Log(Application.dataPath + "/Raw/" + StaticDatas.databaseName);
        Debug.Log(StaticDatas.databasePath + StaticDatas.databaseName);
           using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(Application.dataPath + "/Raw/" + StaticDatas.databaseName))
           {
               bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
               fileStream.Read(bytes,0,int.Parse(fileStream.Length+""));
               fileStream.Close();
               fileStream.Dispose();
           }
           FileStream fs = File.Create(StaticDatas.databasePath + StaticDatas.databaseName);
           fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
       }
         _connection = new SQLiteConnection(filePath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
        CreateDB();
}
```

Error:
Access to the path /var/mobile/containers/dta/application/manythings/DocumentsDatabaseName.db " is denied

IOS: 9.5.3
Unity: 5.5.0f3

**----------------------------------------------------------------**

UPDATE: StaticDatas.databasePath = persistentDataPath

**----------------------------------------------------------------**

UPDATE 2:

Well, I am completely lost...

Here is the code I have:

```
#elif UNITY_IOS

string basePath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath + "Raw" , StaticDatas.databaseName);
string targetPath = Path.Combine(StaticDatas.databasePath , StaticDatas.databaseName );
Debug.Log(basePath);
Debug.Log(targetPath);
if (File.Exists(basePath))
{
    byte[] bytes = null;

        Debug.Log("base path exists");
           using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(basePath))
           {
               Debug.Log("create byte array");
               bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
               Debug.Log(" READ BYTES");
               fileStream.Read(bytes,0,int.Parse(fileStream.Length+""));
               Debug.Log(" CLOSE");
               fileStream.Close();
               Debug.Log("DISPOSE");
               fileStream.Dispose();
           }
           Debug.Log(" Check if dir exists");
          /* if (!Directory.Exists(StaticDatas.databasePath + "/AnnotationTest.app/database/"))
           {
                Debug.Log(" create folder");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(StaticDatas.databasePath + "/AnnotationTest.app/database/");
           }*/
           Debug.Log("Open file");
           FileStream fs = File.Open(targetPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
         Debug.Log("Write file");
           fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
           Debug.Log(" CLOSE STRREAM");
           fs.Close();
       Debug.Log("Connec close");
         _connection = new SQLiteConnection(targetPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
         Debug.Log("sql connect");
        CreateDB();
        Debug.Log(" db made");
}



if (File.Exists("file:" + Application.dataPath + "/Raw/" + StaticDatas.databaseName));
{
    Debug.Log("file datapath raw databasename");
          byte[] bytes = null;

        Debug.Log("base path exists");
           using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("file:" + Application.dataPath + "/Raw/" + StaticDatas.databaseName))
           {
               Debug.Log("create byte array");
               bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
               Debug.Log(" READ BYTES");
               fileStream.Read(bytes,0,int.Parse(fileStream.Length+""));
               Debug.Log(" CLOSE");
               fileStream.Close();
               Debug.Log("DISPOSE");
               fileStream.Dispose();
           }
            FileStream fs = File.Open(targetPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
         Debug.Log("Write file");
           fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
           Debug.Log(" CLOSE STRREAM");
           fs.Close();

         _connection = new SQLiteConnection(targetPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
        CreateDB();
}

#else
            var loadDb = StaticDatas.databasePath + StaticDatas.databaseName;
            File.Copy(loadDb, filePath);
         _connection = new SQLiteConnection(filePath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
        CreateDB();
#endif
```

The first if statement did work for a moment (without `combine`), but now, peanuts.

The second one returns true (`Exists`), but when it reaches the using statement, it says "Could not find a part of the path" (Even if it finds it in the if statement, wtf?)

**----------------------------------------------------------------**

UPDATE 3

It's a miracle! I found it!
Wel, now, SQLite could not open the database, but i found it!

```
string bpa = Application.dataPath + "/Raw/" + StaticDatas.databaseName;

if (File.Exists(bpa))
{
    byte[] b = null;
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(bpa))
    {
        b = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(b, 0, int.Parse(fs.Length+""));
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
    }
    FileStream fsa = File.Open(targetPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    fsa.Write(b,0, b.Length);
    fsa.Close();
    _connection = new SQLiteConnection(targetPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
        CreateDB();
}
else if (File.Exists(basePath))
{

byte[] b = null;
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(basePath))
    {
        b = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(b, 0, int.Parse(fs.Length+""));
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
    }
    FileStream fsa = File.Open(targetPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    fsa.Write(b,0, b.Length);
    fsa.Close();
    _connection = new SQLiteConnection(targetPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
        CreateDB();
}
```

So the correct pathseems to be :

```
 string bpa = Application.dataPath + "/Raw/" + StaticDatas.databaseName;
```

**----------------------------------------------------------------**

UPDATE 4:

Ok, I think I know what the problem is (even if I don't understand it):

I can now get my datas from the streaming assets and copy it to the persistentDatapath, but when I create a connection with the file, SQLite throws an exception:

```
Could not open database file
```

Does someone know why?

**----------------------------------------------------------------**
UPDATE 5:

I do a Combine to create the path "targetPath", in the logs, it shows "/var/mobile/Container/Data/Application/manylettersanddigits/Documents/database.db"

However, in the SQLException, it shows the same but without the slash between Documents and database.db

Comment: A duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433761/file-create-fails-on-iphone-5s)?

Comment: Will look at it, thanks

Comment: I'm confused... Why are you asking about `Application.persistantDataPath`, but then in your code you are using `Application.dataPath?` I'm pretty sure that http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/209108/when-to-use-persistentdatapath-versus-datapath.html answers your question.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I forgot to mention that Static.databasePath is a static string set at persistentDataPath. (Used when I create the file)

Comment: Did that solution I linked work?

Comment: Needed time to build/archive... (thanks apple..). And no, it does not work, access to persistentdatapath (same path as my first post) is denied...

Comment: Why not use `Debug.Log` to find out which line of code is causing that? Otherwise it would be hard to find your problem. Simply put different `Debug.Log` before every line of code where you try to read/write to file.

Comment: That's what I was doing, will answer and update my question to add more info (if I can get more)

Comment: @Andromelus You need to @Zze so that I know you have replied to me! :) Are you sure that `StaticDatas.databasePath == persistentDataPath` when you go to save the data? Maybe it is changing or something

Comment: @Zze I am sure that StaticDatas never change. Their are persistent datas in a static class that is never modified. However, I may have found something that would be the problem, will check it out

Comment: We found out the solution, will answer today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IOS, the current path to streaming assets can be accessed with:

```
Application.dataPath + "/Raw/" + StaticDatas.databaseName;
```

IN THIS CASE, the "Could not open database file" was caused because I was creating 2 connection in the method (shame on me)
Indeed, the second one was making it buggig (same variable for both), was a mistake from me.

Thanks to all.